# Excel Macro SUMIF Why is this returning False?

Tags: excel, vba

Sorry for all the noob questions.  In my macro I am expecting it to return a number from the given range, but all I am getting is FALSE.

```
Cells(N + 2, "V").Formula = "=SUMIF(V2:V" & N & "," & """ & " < " & 0 & """ & ")"
```

thanks1

Comment: `"=SUMIF(V2:V" & N & ",""<0"")"`

Comment: thanks BigBen, I am making this entirely too difficult for myself.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-complicating the concatenation and doubling up of quotes. If you look closely, the `<` does not fall within quotes, hence the boolean `FALSE` result; you're comparing one string to another.

```
"=SUMIF(V2:V" & N & ",""<0"")"
```